# force gcc compilation / ignore error messages

Tags: c, hex

I'm trying to compile some code I found online, but gcc keeps getting me error messages.

Is there any way I can bypass the error, and compile?

```
ttys000$ gcc -o s-proc s-proc.c 
s-proc.c:84:18: error: \x used with no following hex digits
```

Here's the line it keeps bitching about:

```
printf("\x%02x", ((unsigned char *)code)[i]);
```

...

First post on here, so if I broke any rules or wasn't specific enough, let me know.

Comment: This is a good question, but ad hominem attacks are not tolerated -- comments such as "Or might it be you who have a poor understanding of ascii escape characters?"

Comment: OP, you've gotten explanations of what's wrong with your code and you've responded by arrogantly claiming the people helping you don't know what they're doing. This kind of attitude is not going to get you far on SO...

Answer (score 3):

You can't ignore errors<sup>1</sup>.  You can only ignore warnings.  Change the code.

```
printf("\\x%02x", ((unsigned char *)code)[i]);
```

**It's just a guess,** since without documentation or input from the original author of the code, we have no solid evidence for what the code is actually supposed to do.  However, the above correction is *extremely plausible,* it's a simple typo (the original author forgot a `\`), and it's conceivable that the author uses a C compiler which silently ignores the error (Python has the same behavior by design).

The line of code above, or something almost exactly like it, is found in probably tens of thousands of source files across the globe.  It is used for encoding a binary blob using escape sequences so it can be embedded as a literal in a C program.  Similar code appears in JSON, XML, and HTML emitters.  I've probably written it a hundred times.

**Alternatively,** if the code were supposed to print out the character, this would not work:

```
printf("\x%02x", ((unsigned char *)code)[i]);
```

This doesn't work because escape sequences (the things that start with `\`, like `\x42`) are handled by the C compiler, but format strings (the things that start with `%`, like `%02x`) are handled by `printf`.  The above line of code might only work if the order were reversed: if `printf` ran first, *before* you compiled the program.  So no, it doesn't work.

If the author had intended to write literal characters, the following is more plausible:

```
printf("%c", ((unsigned char *)code)[i]);  // clumsy
putchar((unsigned char *)code)[i]);        // simpler
```

So you know either the original author simply typo'd and forgot a single `\` (I make that mistake *all the time*), or the author has no clue.

**Notes:**

<sup>1</sup>: An error means that GCC doesn't *know* what the code is supposed to do, so continuing would be impossible.

Comment: You _can_ ignore warnings, but that doesn't mean you _should_ :-)

Comment: Won't it just print out "\x42" (example) instead of a character then?

Comment: Yes, @Jack, it will. If that's not what you want, you need to specify in the question more clearly what you need.

Comment: Whoever wrote the code is either trying to print out `"\x42"`, or has a very poor understanding of `printf`.

Comment: Maybe this will straighten it out.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Or might it be you who have a poor understanding of ascii escape characters?

Comment: @JackN.White: Context isn't going to help here.  Imagine someone told you to sort the books in "alpabetical" order, but you don't know what "alpabetical" means.  I'm telling you that it's a typo and it should be "alp**h**abetical", and you're saying that the person probably meant "numeric order".

Comment: @JackN.White: The `printf` function does not handle escape sequences (the escape character, ASCII 33, is unrelated to escape sequences, but it must encoded as an escape sequence when used in literals).  The `%02x` string instructs `printf` to emit a **number** as a sequence of hexadecimal digits.  It is unaffected by backslashes in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to add a prefix of `x` to the hex number. If yes, you can drop the `\`:

```
printf("x%02x", ((unsigned char *)code)[i]);
```

The reason you are getting error is `\x` marks the beginning of a hex escape sequence.

Example: `printf("\x43\x4f\x4f\x4c");`

Prints

```
COOL
```

As `C` has an ASCII value of `0x43`.

But in your case the `\x` is not followed by hex digits which causes parse errors. You can see the [C syntax here](http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html) it clearly says:

```
hex-escape   ::=    \x hex-digit ∗
```

Comment: Though, when the code is run, it **will** be followed by two dynamic numbers.

Comment: @JackN.White: You need to understand that you can't have such a string built dynamically. It must be a **constant**.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the \ with another \

```
printf("\\x%02x", ((unsigned char *)code)[i]);
```

By the way, you can't force GCC to continue compilation after an error, as as error is an error because it prevents further logical analysis of the source code which is impossible to resolve.